# How do I output plots from matplotlib to an html template in flask on a ubuntu server?

Tags: python, ubuntu, matplotlib, flask, gunicorn

I am trying to set up a side project on DigitalOcean, and I am using the git framework from https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-xvii-deployment-on-linux to get started.

Within this framework, I have added code within one of the flask routes (/explore) in which I generate a plot with matplotlib, and I want to return this plot as an object when I render the template as the return function of this route. I don't need to save the plot if it can be sent to the template without doing so (e.g with io.BytesIO()), but I have been unable to get the syntax correct to use this approach and get the plot to render in the resulting template.

While my attempts with io.BytesIO() have been unsuccessful, if it would help to output the results with that approach, please let me know how to best utilize it, and I will attempt to run this code with the suggested changes and report the results.

Thank you in advance!

I have tried to save the file and send it to the template, as well as sending the file data via BytesIO(), but neither approach has worked for me.

Below is my attempt to save the file to the static directory and send the image to the template, but a solution that works in this environment with io.BytesIO() or similar without saving the file would be even better.

Here is the code that I added to the explore route in /app/main/routes.py to save the plot image to the static directory and return the path to the template:

```
new_graph_name = url_for('static', filename='tmp_png.png')

plt.savefig(new_graph_name)

return render_template('index.html', url=new_graph_name)
```

Here is the code that I added to the index.html template:

```
{% if url %}

    <img src={{ url }} alt="Chart" height="42" width="42" />

{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

In terms of saving the plot and then displaying it, could you try something similar to the code the below? This has worked for me recently.

In routes.py:

```
@app.route("/")
def index():
   new_graph_name = 'tmp_png'
   plt.savefig('static/images/' + new_graph_name)
   return render_template("index.html", new_graph_name=new_graph_name)
```

In index.html:

```
<img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='images/' + new_graph_name + '.png') }}"
```

With Bytes.IO I think I've tried something like this before:

In routes.py:

```
import io
from io import BytesIO
import base64

img = io.BytesIO()
fig.savefig(img)
img.seek(0)
buffer = b''.join(img)
b2 = base64.b64encode(buffer)
barplot=b2.decode('utf-8')
```

I cannot remember how I displayed it in the .html template but could it just be a matter of passing it as a variable?